# How do I move a table from one sheet to another while rearranging it to a specific format?

Tags: excel

So I want to take a sheet in excel that looks something like this:

| Name | Reason | Justification |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | he's cool | rides a bike |
| George | he's smart | yale |

And have it fill out another sheet that looks like:

| Person | Comments |
| --- | --- |
| Name | Bob |
| Reason | he's cool |
| Justification | rides a bike |
|  |  |
| Person | Comments |
| Name | George |
| Reason | he's smart |
| justification | Yale |
|  |  |

(The blank rows included)

Now this isn't quite a pivot table or a transpose, so I am looking for any direction that would help me accomplish this. Unfortunately I don't know the right words to even google for a good answer.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Press `F11` and copy the following code into a new module ([see how](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2013/12/06/add-run-vba-macro-excel/))

Read the code's comments and adjust it to fit your needs

Run in it by pressing `F8` key ([see how](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/debugging.html))

```
Public Sub rearrangeData()

    ' Set a reference to the source sheet
    Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
    Set sourceSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    ' Set a reference to the target sheet
    Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
    Set targetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    
    ' Set a reference to the source range (including headers)
    Dim sourceRange As Range
    Set sourceRange = sourceSheet.Range("A1:C4")
    
    ' Set a reference to the first cell in target sheet
    Dim targetFirstCell As Range
    Set targetFirstCell = targetSheet.Range("A1")
    
    ' Set a reference to the source range (excluding headers and just the first column)
    Dim sourceBodyRange As Range
    Set sourceBodyRange = sourceRange.Columns(1).Offset(1, 0).Resize(sourceRange.Rows.Count - 1)
    
    ' Store source headers in array
    Dim sourceHeaders As Variant
    sourceHeaders = Application.Transpose(sourceRange.Rows(1).Value)
    
    ' Count number of header cells
    Dim headerCellsCounter As Long
    headerCellsCounter = UBound(sourceHeaders)
    
    ' Start a counter for source cells
    Dim sourceCellCounter As Long
    sourceCellCounter = 1
    
    ' Write the data from source to target (loop through cells in first column and refer to other cells by using offset)
    Dim sourceCell As Range
    For Each sourceCell In sourceBodyRange.Cells
    
        ' Print data headers in target sheet
        targetFirstCell.Offset(sourceCellCounter - 1, 0).Value = "Person"
        targetFirstCell.Offset(sourceCellCounter - 1, 1).Value = "Comments"
    
        ' Print headers in target sheet
        targetFirstCell.Offset(sourceCellCounter, 0).Resize(headerCellsCounter, 1).Value = sourceHeaders

        ' Print row values
        targetFirstCell.Offset(sourceCellCounter, 1).Resize(headerCellsCounter, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(sourceCell.Resize(1, headerCellsCounter).Value)
        
        ' Increase rows
        sourceCellCounter = sourceCellCounter + headerCellsCounter + 2
        
    Next sourceCell

End Sub
```

Let me know if it works